# What are the rules for changing after swimming in appartment complex pool in US

Tags: usa, regulations, swimming

This might be a strange question - in California many apartment complexes have swimming pools but they don't have any changing rooms or anything like that (at least anything that I'd recognize as such). While entering pool seems obvious (just put normal cloths on the swim suite) - what is expected method of exiting?

Comment: I am not sure how is this related to travel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: those pools are for residents, as a guest of a resident your hosts will know. If you're not there as a guest or a resident, you shouldn't be there.

Comment: @jwenting I'm a resident.

Comment: @MeNoTalk well - I though that questions about customs of various countries where you travel. I've seen at least few similar questions.

Comment: @User then ask your neighbours :) I'd guess they just walk to and from the pool in their swimwear, with maybe a towel wrapped around them

Comment: You typically change in your apartment. You live there, after all, right?

Answer (score 5):

Places like that you change in your room and wear a bathrobe or shirt or sarong or just simply wrap your towel around you.  Do the same when you head back to your room, though drying off a bit before leaving the pool area is a polite thing to do ;-)

Comment: Sarong? seriously.. in the US?

Comment: Lots of ladies in the USA use sarong type wraps.  Do you think it is limited to Asia and Africa?

Comment: @Tom No, just (South-East) Asia ;-)